# AltGr problems on Swedish keyboard prevents @, € and $ sign in Redactor WYSIWYG

Tags: html, wysiwyg, fabricjs, redactor

I am developing a solution where the client is using Redactor WYSIWYG editors. For some reason in these Redactor instances AltGr+[2] for example is changing the font size and not typing an @-sign as expected on a Swedish keyboard.

AltGr+[0] should write a } but is causing the textbox to lose focus.

Some AltGr+key works, e.g. "[" (AltGr+[8]) but others don't. I guess there must be a setting for what the AltGr key should do in Redactor but I can't find it nor have they answered my e-mails...

The same behaviour is seen in Fabricjs!

Any ideas?